# Azure Functions Pulse

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Is the Azure Functions Pulse page (which can be displayed by clicking the link "live event stream" after the Monitor tab is selected) still under development?
I noticed that it can only display the chart for Executions Started/Completed/Failed.
Can anyone point me to any documentation on Azure Functions Pulse?

Answer (score 1):

I believe Azure Functions is no longer in preview (this page does not indicate that it is like it used to: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/functions/) but I too have noticed some errors on the pulse page (sometimes it just won't load at all).

I'm sure some of these things will improve over time. Just make sure you've updated your function app to 1.0 (or latest) as logging doesn't work for earlier versions now that they've improved it.